# Stored procedure not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger

I am creating a procedure in a new database. There is no trigger on any table and no procedures exist. I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1303 (2F003): Can't create a PROCEDURE from within another stored routine

What does this mean? How do I solve it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post the actual command throwing this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just what it means. Some commands cannot be invoked from within stored routines. Creation of a stored routine is one of them. As another example, you cannot `LOAD DATA INFILE` from a stored routine.

You may try and do it with a prepared-statement, only to find that `CREATE PROCEDURE` cannot be invoked via prepared statement.

Sorry - no way around this that I know, and I've done my share of search on this.